# decrements the loop value by 2 only in the 6th position

Tags: c, nested-loops

I'm trying to decrements the space loop value by 2 at the row 6 position. After that, as it be like decremented by 1 at the 7th and 8th row so on.

I'm trying to print a pyramid structure with numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int i, j, n, s, p, m;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int num = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("row:%d ", i);
        s = 0;

        for (s = i; s <= n; s++) {  
            if (i == (n / 2) + 1 && j == (n / 2) + 1) {
                s = s + 1;
                printf("%d", s);
            }
//          if ((i == (n / 2) + 1)) {
//              s = s + 2;
////            printf("in:%d ", s);
//          }
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%d", num);
            num = num + 1;
        }

        for (p = 1; p < i; p++) {
            num = num - 1;
            printf("%d", num);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of pyramid you are printing?

If you want to decrease counter by 2 you can use following code:

`for(int i=10; i>0 ; i-=2)`

this will decrease counter by 2 in each loop.